# How to disable a link in desktop size and enable the same in mobile size?

Tags: html

I want to disable a phone call link in desktop size and also i wanna enable the same in mobile size (responsive)

```html
    <a class="single_add_to_cart_button btn btn-theme-colored" href"tel:+18002752273">Order by Phone</a>
```

above given is the code that i used .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .single_add_to_cart_button.btn{
    display:block;
  }
}
 .single_add_to_cart_button.btn{
        display:none;
      }
```

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .single_add_to_cart_button.btn{
    display:block;
  }
}
 .single_add_to_cart_button.btn{
        display:none;
      }
```

```html
    <a class="single_add_to_cart_button btn btn-theme-colored" href"tel:+18002752273">Order by Phone</a>
```

Comment: how to use this can you please tell

Comment: u have any css file